# How to add additional header information to Azure B2C REST call?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am attempting to call an API with Azure B2C during a user journey. The API I'm calling requires two headers to be present -- a client ID and a client secret.

When I define both the `client_id` and `client_secret` values within `<CryptographicKeys>`, I receive an error that only one key is expected for `ApiKeyHeader` authentication type. So it appears I cannot provide multiple headers this way.

Is there a way to allow multiple headers in this way? Or alternatively, is there some other way I'm unaware of where I can provide the client ID as a header without referencing it as a key, since it doesn't need to be secured in my case?

My technical profile currently looks like this (scrubbed of identifying information)

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="Call-Workflow-On-Registration">
  <DisplayName>Call Workflow for User upon Registration</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <!-- TODO: Remove ngrok URL in favor of actual URL. The ngrok URL forwards to the listening developer's machine so we can examine calls. -->
    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">http://scrubbed.ngrok.io/users/registrationRequests</Item>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">ApiKeyHeader</Item>
    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
    <Item Key="ClaimUsedForRequestPayload">workflowRequestBody</Item>
    <Item Key="DefaultUserMessageIfRequestFailed">Cannot process your request right now, please try again later. (Reference ID: 1827346)</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="client_id" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_WorkflowClientIdNonProd" />
    <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_WorkflowClientSecretNonProd" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <InputClaimsTransformations>
    <!-- This generates the JSON body using the user's object ID -->
    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GenerateWorkflowBody" />
  </InputClaimsTransformations>
  <InputClaims>
    <!-- This claim is provided by the InputClaimsTransformation -->
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="workflowRequestBody" />
  </InputClaims>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score -1):

As you have found, only one cryptographic key is allowed in the REST technical profile when using `ApiKeyHeader`.

In the past I have seen people either specify the Client ID in the URL, or make an Azure Function that can "proxy" requests between B2C and the end REST API in question.

Comment: Yup, using a "proxy" is the way to go. Then you are free to do anything.